# How to pass env variables to a custom container in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, docker, next.js, azure-web-app-service, containers

I've built a NextJS application that is being sent to an Azure Container Registry and then sent to an Azure Web App, but I'm having trouble setting the environment variables. Even though I set them in the App Settings they are not being passed to my custom container, I have already tried to pass them somehow through the startup file or command in the deployment center but I was unsuccessful. Here's my DockerFile, if anyone can help me I'd be grateful

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

No matter how I try to pass the startup command, the container is always started with the same docker run

```
docker run -d --expose=3000 --name name_0_2654d0f8 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=false -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=3000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=websitename -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=hostnamedemo -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=webinstanceIDmock -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 acrname.azurecr.io/imagename:latest
```

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux

Comment: Check https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2021/04/buildtime-vs-runtime-environment-variables-nextjs-docker/

Comment: is it running fine locally??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple `express` application

This Worked For me

**`app.js`:**

```js
const express = require('express');

const ENV = process.env.VAR
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello, World! ${ENV}`);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**`Dockerfile`:**

```
FROM  node:lts-alpine

ENV  NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR  /usr/src/app

COPY  ["package.json",  "package-lock.json*",  "npm-shrinkwrap.json*",  "./"]

RUN  npm  install  --production  --silent  &&  mv  node_modules  ../

COPY  .  .

EXPOSE  3000

RUN  chown  -R  node  /usr/src/app

USER  node

CMD  ["node",  "app.js"]
```

#### Process:

- I pushed Image to Azure Container Registry

[image]

- I created a Container Instance to run the image.

[image]

- I deployed a container web app

[image]

- I used Image for webapp

[image]

- I passed the value in `Environment Variables`.

[image]

### `OUTPUT`:

#### locally:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --env VAR='HelloVivek' node:lts
```

[image]

[image]

#### Azure:

[image]

> ##### Note: It takes some time to reflect the variable value.

Comment: The container instance doesn't worked for me, however the ENV  NODE_ENV=production in Dockerfile work and the vars passed to the container