# How to deploy my nodejs project in Azure web service using github?

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, github-actions

Now, I am trying to deploy my nodejs project in Azure web service.
This is the original project.
[Librechat](https://github.com/danny-avila/LibreChat)
This is the chatbot project mostly like framework.
I cloned this project and customized the code for me. Now, I am gonna deploy this project using github actions + Azure but that is not working well.
The error is different sometimes.
I am using this workflow for actoins :=> [Azure WebApp](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-webapp)

But I don't see any specific npm command in there.
I am new in Azure so I need some help.
To install npm of that librechat, you should use `npm ci` and to build, `npm run frontend`.
And to run the project in production mode, you should use `npm run backend`
I am not sure if that [Azure WebApp](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-webapp) has default npm command to run the project.

```yaml
name: Deploy ChatG to Azure ChatG Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ChatG-App
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  NODE_VERSION: '20.x' # set this to the node version to use

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: npm install and build
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run frontend
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          slot-name: 'production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

Comment: You need to use Docker or Container Registry for this project and you need to pass required environment variables.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78154917/how-to-pass-env-variables-to-a-custom-container-in-azure-web-app/78165790#78165790